directories have become links to themselves
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 yesterday. Today I installed dolphin (snap).
Now almost all of my directories have turned into links to themselves, giving me a message in Natulis "Sorry, could not display all the contents of "Documents". Error opening directory '/home/bill/Documents'. Too many levels of symbolic links.
The terminal shows - lrwxrwxrwx 1 bill bill 18 Oct 12 15:02 ((in red)) Desktop-> /home/bill/Desktop
Directories affected - Desktop, Documents, Music, Pictures,Public, Templates,Videos.
Not affected - Downloads, Snap
~/.config/user-dirs.dirs shows the line "XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/"
So, what is going on? How to change the 'l' to a 'd'?
Thanks for the help, Bill

The link above has the info for a fix - remove the directories, recreate them, edit the XDG file , and put a file in the directories. For those, like me, who are new to this, the command to open the file is <xdg-open ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs> I used, as suggested, </Documents$ touch .empty_file> and that worked until I started the next day, Only three of the directories were recursive links. So I created a one-line text file and put that in all of the directories. That seems to have solved the problem
